# TypeScript/JSDoc generics for class prototype as property of another class

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, jsdoc

I have a class with a method that creates an instance of a configured prototype:

```
class A {}
class B {}

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Options
 * @property {typeof A|typeof B} type
 */

class Foo {

  /**
   * @param {Options} options
   */
  constructor(options) {
    /** @type {typeof A|typeof B} */
    this.type = options.type;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {A|B}
   */
  create() {
    return new this.type();
  }
}

const foo = new Foo({type: A});
const created = foo.create();
```

This works fine, but now I'd like to make the class generic in a way that the return type of the create() method is determined by the `type` option passed to the constructor.

I tried the following, but without success:

```
/**
 * @template {A|B} Type
 */
class Foo {

  /**
   * @param {Options} options
   */
  constructor(options) {

    /** @type {typeof Type} */
    this.type = options.type;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {Type}
   */
  create() {
    return new this.type();
  }
}
```

The problem is this section:

```
    /** @type {typeof Type} */
    this.type = options.type;
```

The `@type {typeof Type}` is not accepted, with the following error:

> 'Type' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)

Comment: You'll want a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures). No idea if jsdoc supports that.